# Serializing a BitmapImage in WinRT

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

```
public static async Task SaveFileAsync(string FileName, T data)
{
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
    serializer.WriteObject(memStream, data);

    StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(FileName,
        CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    using (Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        await memStream.CopyToAsync(stream);
        await stream.FlushAsync();
    }
}

public static async Task<T> RestoreFileAsync(string FileName)
{
    T result = default(T);
    try
    {
        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(FileName);
        using (IInputStream inStream = await file.OpenSequentialReadAsync())
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            result = (T)serializer.ReadObject(inStream.AsStreamForRead());
            return result;
        }
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

I'm using these methods to serialize my data,
but i have a class that contains an image,

```
[DataMember]
Public Image img{get;set;}
```

I'm trying to serialize it.
I'm doing the following actually

```
var thumb = await item.GetThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.PicturesView,
                        1000, Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailOptions.UseCurrentScale);

BitmapImage bmg = new BitmapImage();
bmg.SetSource(thumb);
Image img = new Image();
img.Source = bmg;
```

i tried to serialize the bitmapImage it self but it is the same problem.
i keep getting this error, and my BitmapImage has an attribute.

> Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.

Answer (score 0):

`DataContractSerializer` won't work with images. You should either use [`BitmapEncoder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx) (if you are dealing with `WriteableBitmap` or simply serialize the source address of your `BitmapImage`. If the bitmap was loaded from a local path or a temporary URL and you want to persist the entire bitmap - you can't extract the bitmap bits from `BitmapImage` anyway and so you need to either download the source file from the original source URL or copy the local file you loaded. You could then either save that copy as a loose file or serialize as say Base64 inside of your `DataContractSerializer`-created XML.

Comment: Filip, I'm getting the image as a thumbnail from a video as you can see,
the problem is i dont have a name to copy to my local folder and retrieve it as Uri. as you can see in the code above, i need to save either the bitmapImage, or the source of it, and i dont have any idea to do the both operations.
If you can provide a simple example, that will be great,
thank you.

Comment: There is no simple example. You can't serialize the BitmapImage itself, period. If it was loaded using a Uri - you can save the Uri or use it to load the bytes of the original image. If it was loaded with a stream - you need to keep track of the source of that stream and when you need to serialize the BitmapImage - you serialize that (already serialized) stream instead. BTW, if your video thumbnail question is solved can you accept an answer or add your own if you found another?

Comment: if you mean that how to get a thumbnail from a video, the code is above, var thumb = item.GetThumbnailAsync(...), where item is a StorageFile, sorry, but I'm not really good in english. :D

Comment: last thing,
i found this code.
var stm = thumb.AsStream();
byte[] bytes = new byte[Convert.ToUInt32(thumb.Size)];
stm.Position = 0;  await stm.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
 InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
                        DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(randomAccessStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0)); writer.WriteBytes(bytes);
await writer.StoreAsync();
BitmapImage imagen = new BitmapImage();
                        imagen.SetSource(randomAccessStream);
this might work right ?

Comment: This seems roughly like something you could do to convert your [StorageItemThumbnail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.storageitemthumbnail.aspx) to a `BitmapImage`, though it feels like it might be a bit too much since it looks like copying the stream to a buffer, then writing to another stream before loading the `BitmapImage` from it, but you were saying you wanted to serialize it. Do you want to serialize the randomAccessStream that has the bytes of your compressed image?

Comment: i want to serialize lets say the randomAccessStream and get it and bind it to a gridview for example. this is all i want. :)
it can be done but the question is how.

Comment: `InMemoryRandomAccessStream` is already serialized. It's a buffer that in your case contains the bytes of the compressed image. You can just bind these to your `GridView` items and it should work. It's off topic of this question though.