# Serializing a thumbnail image WinRT

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, thumbnails, c#-5.0

I'm getting the thumbnail image from a video, all I need is to serialize it
how to do that.
I've been doing some searches and I get nothing.
I have the code of how to serialize an object, but I want to serialize the thumbnail image itself to get it later when I start my app up again.

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14997495/41071)?

Comment: Serialize it to what?

Comment: svick it doesn't but i need to get more answers :D

Answer (score 0):

you have an image or video feed ?
if its an image, you can easily do it.

Have a look at http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/ it provides extension methods to WriteableBitmap class that allows Resize in addition to tons of other things.

What you need to do is
* Load the image into writeable bitmap
* Resize it using extension methods
* Have the image to stream ?

Comment: Hermit im getting the image from a video using GetThumbnailAsync(..)

Comment: did you change your question ? there is nothing like Serialising your thumbnail however you can save it to file system. this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349611/how-to-resize-image-in-c-sharp-winrt-winmd shows how to manipulate image and save it